Import form data from JIRA to snowflake
I am using JIRA token to read data into matiilion and send it to snowflake. I can see all tables except for "form" data. How to get this data or which table has this data?


JIRA has a separate API for Forms, which is different to the Jira Software Cloud REST API the Matillion Jira Query component accesses. I think you will need to create your own Custom Connector to use the Forms API.

Can you please tell me how to do it?

The Matillion component connects to the Jira Platform API which works with the objects in your screenshot. I cannot find any reference to Forms in this API.
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/#about
Jira also has a Forms API. I was wondering if this is what you require? You may be able to use API Query/Extract to work with it.
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/forms/rest/intro
